# Sending XML data in POST using Guzzle

Tags: php, xml, soap, guzzle

I am trying to scrape a webpage, I don't know whether the site has a bad design or I can't understand the principle. I am trying to request a report from the server.

Initially I tried to send the request from Firefox & Intercepted the data. It sends a POST request to the server in this form,

```
https://<site>/alpha/beta?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c
```

The POST Data Contains,

```
Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
<soap:Envelope>
<soap:Body>
<GetUpdatedObjects>
<Operation>
<Target>
<Id>Document</Id>
<Type>Document</Type>
</Target>
<Operator>GetPage</Operator>
<Oprand>
<Name>blah...blah</Name>
<Value>2015-11-01</Value>
</Oprand>
</Operation>
</GetUpdatedObjects>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I was wondering how I can send this request with the Guzzle library. Is it even possible? Because I have the login & other scrape function written in with Guzzle. Any input would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$client = new Client();
$req = new Request('POST', $this->url, $headers, $xml);
$resp = $client->send($req);
var_dump($resp->getBody()->getContents());
```

but i have issues with catching exceptions and errors --- guzzle6.